# Using javascript request result as value in <progress>

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar, getelementbyid

I am trying to measure upload percentage and output the result as plain text and as a value for a progress bar or width of a div.

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        var percent = event.loaded / event.total;
        var progress = document.getElementById('upload_progress');

        while (progress.hasChildNodes()) {
            progress.removeChild(progress.firstChild);
        }
        progress.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Math.round(percent * 100) + ' %'));

    }
});
```

Above is a part of what i am currently using and it outputs a rounded percentage + % to the div with the id 'upload_progress'. I would like to also output the percentage to a progress bar that is using the html5 progress tag. Something like this `<progress id="progressbar" value="X" max="100"></progress>` where X is from javascript.

```
var bar = document.getElementById('progressbar')
bar.value = (Math.round(percent * 100))
```

I figured adding this where appropriate would help but it does not seem to be working at all.

Sorry if this should be obvious i am new to javascript and programming in general. How could i make this work?

Thanks

Comment: var bar **=** document.…?

Comment: wow yeah thanks turns out it was just that and some typos, i feel so stupid. i guess thats what i get for trying to code at 4AM

Comment: When I just type out `<progress max="100" value="25">` and even use JS it seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you get the elements after DOM is completely loaded. 
Also, you should set the progress percentage `value` inside the `progress` event handler.

```
var progress, bar;
window.onload = function() {
    progress = document.getElementById('upload_progress');
    bar = document.getElementById('progressbar');
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        var percent = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
        bar.value = percent;
        // other code here...
    }
});
```

Why are you doing so much DOM manipulation? You should just set the `innerHTML` of the corresponding `div` to show the percentage text.

```
// instead of this:
//while (progress.hasChildNodes()) {
//    progress.removeChild(progress.firstChild);
//}
//progress.appendChild(document.createTextNode(percent + ' %'));

// You can do this:
progress.innerHTML = percent + ' %';
```

And finally make sure you are calling `request.open(...);`
Apart from that I don't see any problem with your code.